# How to remove oil from the new keyboard? (Macbook 2021 14 inch)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

After two weeks of use, I started to see oil smudges on my keyboard. Since then, I've been religiously cleaning my keyboard (microfibre + 70% rubbing alch) and hands every day, but it doesn't seem to get any better.

I'm wondering if anyone has other suggestions or if this is a common problem with the new keyboards?

For reference, I've previously used the macbook 2012 and 2015 keyboards without having oil smudges until after about 3 years of careless use, so within 2 weeks was a bit of a surprise.

Suggestions or comments are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Can you supply a photo to show the extent of the issue? A certain of amount of 'finger grease' might be inevitable, particularly in hot, humid climes. And you're certain that no one else might be using it (or a cat walking over it)?

Comment: I wouldn't use rubbing alcohol on plastic, it will rot it. Microfibre & water only, as anything else reduces the efficiency of the microfibre.

Comment: Never used any type of alcohol on my keyboards, but worn the covering away to the clear plastic on several keys.

Comment: @benwiggy sorry i'm not sure how to add a photo, but yes just me using it.

Ok, I'll try just microfibre and water and report back.

Comment: Tried microfibre and water. Worked pretty well, but some residue is still left on the keyboard.